# What widget can be used to preview pdf file in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I’m creating a application which creates a pdf file as result, I want a widget that can preview pdf file just like qtable widget for excel, please suggest what widget can be used to preview pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

[qpageview](https://pypi.org/project/qpageview/)

This is one way to display a PDF.